# Mailkit.Net hangs on smtpClient.ConnectAsync(), throws no exception until Task timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, mailkit

Recently I run into a problem in one of our older applications. All of a sudden, application stopped sending registration/reset password emails to it's users. After some debugging, I discovered that the cause is a strange behaviour of Mailkit SmtpClient class. Problem occurs in following code:

```
public async Task Execute(EmailMessage email)
{
    var mimeMessage = CreateMimeMessageFromEmailMessage(email);

    using var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();

    await smtpClient.ConnectAsync(Options.SmtpServer, Options.Port, MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.None);
    await smtpClient.AuthenticateAsync(Options.Username, Options.Password);
    await smtpClient.SendAsync(mimeMessage);
    await smtpClient.DisconnectAsync(true);
}
```

Error occurs every time in ConnectAsync() method, hovewer, it throws no exception, just freeze in this method for some time (about a minute), then it just throws Task cancelled with nothing mailkit specific.

At first, I thought that address to server, port or security options might be wrong, but we are using the same settings (and the same code!) in some of our other applications and they seem to work fine. It should also not be caused by something in my PC/network configuration, as other developers also run into same error when working on this program. I also tried to use Options for different email, but the error remains.

Any idea how to find a cause of this error, how to debug the problem when no exception is thrown etc.?

Comment: Have you checked if you're able to establish a connection to the SMTP Server? Try telnet on that port.

Comment: @RamKumaran I am little confused. I tried to test the same port I am using in my application (port 465, according to smtp setup documentation of our email provider) and it indeed didn't connect. Hovewer, I found on their website that for telnet testing, I should use port 25 instead (and it connected). I am seriously confused

Comment: What you did initially is correct, the port is not open or you're unable to establish a successful connection. Check this link : https://www.opcsupport.com/s/article/How-do-I-ping-and-telnet-to-test-a-tunneller-connection

Even if the port is open, something is preventing you to make successful connection, check firewall too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to your comments, the following line is failing when the port used is 465:

```
await smtpClient.ConnectAsync(Options.SmtpServer, Options.Port, MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.None);
```

That's your problem. You are trying to use port 465 while *also* using `SecureSocketOptions.None`.

You need to use `SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect` with port 465.

Port 465 is the SSL-port, but you are telling MailKit to connect and treat it as if it was connecting to a plain-text port. Obviously, that won't work.